# how to add validation in jquery image size? and this code is below

Tags: jquery

how to add validation in jquery image size?
I do not quite understand jquery, I hope that friends can help me

and this code is below.

---

```
$ (function () {enter code here
$ ('# press'). click (function () {
  var file = $ ('# image'). val (); // Grab Value
  var extensions = ['jpg', 'png']; // Variable array for determination Extensions
   if (file) {
    var ambilekstensi = file.split ('.'); // Take Extensions
        ambilekstensi = ambilekstensi.reverse ();
    if ($ .inArray (ambilekstensi [0] .toLowerCase (), extension)> -1) {
           alert ('Sipp ..');
         }
    else {
           alert ('Type Photos should be .jpg / .png'); // If the extension is not suitable Alert
         }
       }
   else
       {
          alert ('Select Images'); // Alert if the value null
       }
   return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the image is presented, Use .length Instead of .val(). I have modified your code here. just try it out and let me know.

```
$ (function () {
$ ('# press'). click (function () {
  // remove this line and check src is presented for the image
  //var file = $ ('# image'). val (); // Grab Value
  var extensions = ['jpg', 'png']; // Variable array for determination Extensions
   // remove this line too
   //if (file) {
   // add this line
    if ($('# image').src.length > 0) { 
    var ambilekstensi = file.split ('.'); // Take Extensions
        ambilekstensi = ambilekstensi.reverse ();
    if ($ .inArray (ambilekstensi [0] .toLowerCase (), extension)> -1) {
           alert ('Sipp ..');
         }
    else {
           alert ('Type Photos should be .jpg / .png'); // If the extension is not suitable Alert
         }
       }
   else
       {
          alert ('Select Images'); // Alert if the value null
       }
   return false;
    });

});
```